# what does Compare compare at CompareAndSwap at AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet()?

Tags: java, concurrency, atomic, compare-and-swap

I know CompareAndSwap is used under hood of methods like AtomicInteger.incrementAndGet() in java concurrent,it works like endless cycle until it successful and blocked it's thread

> It compares the contents of a memory location with a given value and,
>   only if they are the same, modifies the contents of that memory
>   location to a new given value. This is done as a single atomic
>   operation. The atomicity guarantees that the new value is calculated
>   based on up-to-date information; if the value had been updated by
>   another thread in the meantime, the write would fail. The result of
>   the operation must indicate whether it performed the substitution;
>   this can be done either with a simple boolean response (this variant
>   is often called compare-and-set), or by returning the value read from
>   the memory location (not the value written to it).

So what it the **given value** and **contents of a memory location** in incrementAndGet()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When one thread sees the current value, for example, `1`, then it increments it to `2` as `given value`, and compare `2` to the real value in memory at current moment.

If it successes, `2` will be returned.

Otherwise, it will retrieve the newest value, let's say it `x`, and increment to `x + 1` as given value.

...

This procedure will continue until a successful comparison.

Comment: you wrote "and compare 2 to the real value in memory at current moment", so what should be the **real value in memory** to satisfy the thread?

Comment: does **2 as given value** mean the thread keep 2 at its registry as a local copy? What if it's volatile?